# The best loss function for pixelwise binary classification in keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I built a deep learning model which accept image of size 250*250*3 and output 62500(250*250) binary vector  which contains 0s in pixels that represent the background and 1s in pixels which represents ROI. 
My model is based on DenseNet121 but when i use softmax as an activation function in last layer and categorical cross entropy loss function , the loss is nan.
What is the best loss and activation function that i can use it in my model?
What is the difference between binary cross entropy and categorical cross entropy loss function?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the best loss and activation function that i can use it in my model?

- Use `binary_crossentropy` because every output is independent, not mutually exclusive and can take values 0 or 1, use `sigmoid` in the last layer.

Check this interesting [question/answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207794/what-loss-function-for-multi-class-multi-label-classification-tasks-in-neural-n)

> What is the difference between binary cross entropy and categorical cross entropy loss function?

[Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9302/the-cross-entropy-error-function-in-neural-networks) is a good set of answers to that question.

**Edit 1:** My bad, use `binary_crossentropy`.

After a quick look at the [code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2840) (again) I can see that keras uses:

- for `binary_crossentropy` -> `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`

  > [(From tf docs)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits): Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in which each class is independent and not mutually exclusive. For instance, one could perform multilabel classification where a picture can contain both an elephant and a dog at the same time.
- for `categorical_crossentropy` -> `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`

  > [(From tf docs)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits): Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in which the classes are mutually exclusive (each entry is in exactly one class). For example, each CIFAR-10 image is labeled with one and only one label: an image can be a dog or a truck, but not both.

Comment: Since he's got only one channel in the output, Bachground x Foreground, It should be a `binary_crossentropy`.